# Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'undefined is not a number' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have this input : 
`<input class="number " type= "text"  pInputText [readonly]="" formControlName="id" [required]="" plmNumberFormatter [value]="data?.id   | numberPipe" />`

When putting the cursor on the input I get undefined as a value in the input.

This my TS :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.createForm();
    this.keys.split(',').forEach(item => {
      set(this.data, item, null);
    });
```

and this is my pipe :

```
transform(value: number | string, fractionSize?: number): string {
      const numberValue = transformToNumber(value, this.profile.getCurrentProfile());
    let retNumber = Number(numberValue);
      return this.decimalPipe.transform(retNumber,  this.profile.getDigitsInfo(), this.profile.getLocale());
  }
```

What is wrong?

Angular version: 7.3.9

Comment: seems like your data?.id is undefined and can not be converted to number or string.  your second pipe param is optional, so, I think this is ignored (no problem there).

Comment: Please provide some code with your 'data' object structure, and how it is initialized

Comment: data:any = {};
keys = `rib,accountType,id`;
 this.keys.split(',').forEach(item => {
      set(this.data, item, null);
    });

Comment: Can you please say what is the `set()` method?

Comment: set is a method from lodash . 
https://lodash.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should declare data first. Like the following:

```
...
public data: object = {}
...

constructor() {
    this.form = this.createForm();
    this.keys.split(',').forEach(item => {
        set(this.data, item, null);
    });
    this.data = { ...this.data };
}
```

See that you don't create a new reference to the data object.
Angular looks for reference changes so it is important to create a new reference.

html:

```
<input class="number " type= "text"  pInputText [readonly]="" formControlName="id" [required]="" plmNumberFormatter [value]="data.id | numberPipe" />
```

Comment: maybe try using a (change) function instead of a value pipe

Comment: the problem is that I want to add a test if the value ( data.id ) is undefined it's won't be shown in the input. How can I do that?

Comment: undefined value won't be displayed... can you try to explain what outcome are you looking for?